# Not able to check maven version

Tags: maven

When i run the below command i am not getting the maven version. java -version works perfectly.

**>mvn -v
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Below are the environment variables set

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11
M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.3
M2=%M2_HOME%\bin

PATH=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2%;
```

Comment: don't you need "double quotes" around the path when there's a space in it? "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11" and "C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.3"

Comment: java --version is working well without quotes

Comment: excellent. Glad you've accepted an answer already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the folder apache-maven-3.5.3 to C:\apache-maven-3.5.3

Make sure you are adding environment variable to SYSTEM VARIABLES:

M2_HOME = C:\apache-maven-3.5.3

Then add %M2_HOME%\bin to the PATH system variable.

Try also running the command line with Administrator privileges.

Comment: it doesn't fix the issue

Comment: Try printing the variables in the command line if you get all correct:
    echo %M2_HOME% and echo %M2%

Comment: Try also running the command line with Administrator privileges.

Comment: how do i set M2 and M2_HOME to PATH system variable.

Comment: it sowrks now after i set the varibales to  PATH system variable.

Comment: Great! Yes, environment variables must be set under SYSTEM VARIABLES to be safe, rather than user-specific variables.

Comment: Remove M2_HOME and only use the path to the maven installation in particular the bin directory and put that into your PATH variable...